# Print line content of a xtext parser error

Tags: java, xtext

are there any ways to print the content of line if an error occurs during parsing a file via xtext into the log file? Currently, all I get is a line number but this is not enough to find a problem if you do have only a log file.

I didn't find a section in the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html) for this. Do you have any idea or resource to help?

Comment: which log file are you referring to

Comment: just a simple log4j log file.

Comment: and how do you call xtext / the validator

Comment: e.g. ig you have a resource in your hand
    
    if (r instanceof XtextResource) {
  XtextResource xr = (XtextResource)r;
  for (INode e : xr.getParseResult().getSyntaxErrors()) {
   System.out.println(e.getSyntaxErrorMessage());
   System.out.println(e.getStartLine());
  }
 }

Comment: The parser is injected. Then I call parse method and provide a Reader object: IParser.parse(Reader). As Result I do get an EObject if it works otherwise just an Exception.

Comment: why do you simply parse and not link etc?

Comment: because, it will never be executed, all I need is to be sure the file is correct.

Comment: well then getting the errors and texts is the same anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
IParser parser = i.getInstance(IParser.class);
    IParseResult parseResult = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new StringInputStream("element a\nelement a\nxxxx")));
    for (INode e : parseResult.getSyntaxErrors()) {
        System.out.println(e.getSyntaxErrorMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getStartLine());
                    System.out.println(e.getText());
    }
```

and if that is not enhough

```
for (INode x : parseResult.getRootNode().getLeafNodes()) {
            if (x.getStartLine()==e.getStartLine()) {
                System.out.print(x.getText());
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Comment: thx, I totally missed the part with the getSyntaxErrorMessage(). I will test this tomorrow.